# how to programmatically create/populate the view of a appwidget in android

Tags: android, android-appwidget

Say I have a framelayout as the view of a appwidget. The framelayout have several children to form a layered structure. Depending on the application logic, the children in the framelayout can be removed or added. Is it possible to do so programmatically since a view of appwidget is a RemoteView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html search for the addView method.